# How do I get rid of "the connected device is unable to access data" notification

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, popup

When I connect my phone to my job computer the phone shows a "the connected device is unable to access data" dialog from time to time. I think this is just annoying - if I want to access files from my computer I would notice that when I try and if I don't I couldn't care less.

Is there a way to disable that popup from appearing? I'm using a Galaxy Note 9 (in case that make any difference).